# How to convert tabs into dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of tabs that are being displayed. I would like to convert them into a dropdown when i use `@media` query aka when i need to make them responsive. Each set of tabs displays its own contents.

I tried many methods from stackoverflow but none fit my case.

```
 <ul class="resources__tab-controls">
            <li class="resources__tabs resources__all-tabs" onclick="openResources(event, 'entrepreneur')">
                <a href="#">
                    Entrepreneurship
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="resources__tabs"  onclick="openResources(event, 'social')">
                <a href="#">
                    Social
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="resources__tabs " onclick="openResources(event, 'technology')">
                <a>
                    Technology
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="lastTab">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    More <span class="caret"></span>
               </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapsed">

               </ul>
           </li>
     </ul>
```

I tried to set them into a dropdown when size of the screen is small using this logic but I am stuck in an infinite loop.

```
 function autocollapse() {

    let tabs = $('.resources__tab-controls');
    let tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();

    if (tabsHeight >= 50) {
      while(tabsHeight > 50) {
        //console.log("new"+tabsHeight);

        let children = tabs.children('li:not(:last-child)');
        let count = children.size();
        $(children[count-1]).prependTo('#collapsed');

        tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();
      }
    }
    else {
        while(tabsHeight < 50 && (tabs.children('li').size()>0)) {

        let collapsed = $('#collapsed').children('li');
        let count = collapsed.size();
        $(collapsed[0]).insertBefore(tabs.children('li:last-child'));
        tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();
      }
      if (tabsHeight>50) { 
          autocollapse();
      }
    }

   };

   $(document).ready(function() {

        autocollapse(); // when document first loads

      $(window).on('resize', autocollapse); // when window is resized

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite loop is due to the following block:

```
while(tabsHeight > 50) {
  let children = tabs.children('li:not(:last-child)');
  let count = children.size();
  $(children[count-1]).prependTo('#collapsed');
  tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();
}
```

What happens is that `children` becomes an empty list, due to the fact that there are no remaining list-items. Which means that `tabsHeight` isn't changing anymore and stays above `50`.

A simpler approach can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Comment: in this, i have to make a new set of `ul li` to get the effect i need. Is there a solution to that while loop? If there is, can u please suggest some way because I want to avoid creating another set of `ul li`

Comment: If you do want to fix this `while` it's a simple case of expanding the `tabsHeight > 50`condition to also check if `tabs.children('li:not(:last-child)')`returns any elements. If not, then the `while` loop should stop (since that means all elements have been moved into your "More"-block).